# JPA cascade Set content

Tags: jpa, associations, one-to-many, cascade, many-to-one

Do you know why this:

```
class Owner {
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner",
    cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  public Set<Storage> storages
  ...

class Storage {
  @ManyToOne
  public Owner owner
  ...
```

doesn't work as expected:

```
Storage s = new Storage("S1")
Owner o = new Owner("O1")
o.storages.add(s)
...
em.persistAndFlush(o)
...
s = Storage.get...
assert(s.owner != null, "Storage does not have an Owner")
o = Order.get...
assert(!o.storages.isEmpty, "Owner does not have any Storage")
```

The test fails:

```
[info] - Storage *** FAILED ***
[info]   Storage does not have an Owner
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question gets asked once every 2 days. JPA uses the owning side of a bidirectional association to know if an association exists. The owning side is the side where there is *no* `mappedBy` attribute. So, to tell JPA that an association exists between owner and storage, you must set the owner of the storage:

```
s.setOwner(o);
```

Comment: Does it matter where the CascadeType.ALL is? Beacause now, I get "Owner does not have any Storage"...

Comment: It's **your** responsibility to maintain the coherence of the object graph. You must initialize both sides of the association. If you just set the owning side, the association will be persisted, but Hibernate won't initialize the other side for you. If you reload the objects in a **new** transaction, JPA will populate both sides for you. During the current transaction, it will return objects from its cache, just as you initialized them.